# Any limit of extending single value properties via Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, message, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm looking into extending single value properties for the message endpoint using Microsoft Graph API. Is there a limit on the number of properties that can be extended in single request?

`/messages/delta?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id eq 'LONG 0x0E08') or (Id eq 'String 0x007D') or (Id eq 'Integer 0x1081'))`

Also, are there any performance concerns or drawbacks associated with extending a large number of properties?

Comment: "*Also, are there any performance concerns or drawbacks associated with extending a large number of properties?*" Can you be more specific as to your concern? Obviously retrieving more data will mean a higher performance load.

Comment: I think the only limit you would hit would be the maximum URL length of 2048 characters. Large properties like 0x007D are going to hit the performance because of the size it can be (eg it all the message headers) based on the number of messages/changes you returning. Other things that factor into performance is the total number of items in the folder

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific limit documented by Microsoft for the number of single value extended properties that can be extended in a single request using the Microsoft Graph API. However, there are some practical considerations and performance concerns to keep in mind when extending a large number of properties:

**Performance Impact**: Extending a large number of properties can increase the payload size of your requests and responses, which may affect the performance of your application. It can lead to longer response times and increased bandwidth usage, especially if you're working with a large dataset.

**Complexity:** Managing a large number of extended properties can make your code more complex and harder to maintain. You need to keep track of the property names and their values.

**Rate Limits:** While there may not be a specific limit on the number of extended properties, Microsoft Graph API has rate limits in place. Extensive use of extended properties can result in hitting these rate limits, which might temporarily throttle your application's access to the API.

**API Versioning:** Be aware that Microsoft may introduce changes to the API over time. Extending a large number of properties may make your code more susceptible to breaking changes in future API versions.

To mitigate these concerns, consider the following best practices:

Only extend properties that are necessary for your application. Avoid extending properties that you don't plan to use.

If you need to work with a large number of properties, consider batching your requests to the API to avoid hitting rate limits and manage the payload size.

Keep your code organized and well-documented, especially when dealing with a large number of properties, to make it easier to maintain.